# Hiding/Showing side panel

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I am trying to hide/show a panel on the right side of my screen when a button is clicked, however, it is not working exactly as I intended.

Here are a few pics:

`Start`

This is what my screen originally looks like at startup.

[image]

When I click `Resize Grid` for the first time, this is what the page looks like:

This is actually what I want to happen. The images have shrunk appropriately so that they can all still be viewed.

[image]

Two further clicks of `Resize Grid` results in the 1st image shown above being re-displayed, followed by this:

[image]

Can anyone help me with this so that this doesn't occur?

Here is my code so far:

`XAML`

```
<Window x:Class="VideoManager.MoviePanel"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MoviePanel" Height="1024" Width="1463" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"  Width="Auto">
            <Image Width="200" Height="300" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding Image}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="movie_grid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="1463">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="102" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView
                  Name="MovieListView"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path = movies}" Margin="0,0,0,0" SelectionChanged="MovieListView_SelectionChanged" Grid.Row="1">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="5" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
    <TextBlock x:Name="SampleTextBlock"  Margin="1228,36,49,43" >
        <InlineUIContainer>
            <TextBox Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Search" Width="200" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
        </InlineUIContainer>
    </TextBlock>
    <Button Content="Home" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="46,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_Home"/>
    <Button Name="collapse" Content="Resize Grid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="176,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
    <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width = "0" Height="872" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="sidebar" SelectionChanged="sidebar_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <TextBlock Text="hello"/>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

`C#`

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

        // collapse main grid and show sidebar
        if (this.collapse.Name == "collapse") 
        {
            MovieListView.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(0,0,280,0);   
            sidebar.Width = 280;
            sidebar.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(1183,0,0,0);
            this.collapse.Name = "expand";
        }

        // expand main grid and hide sidebar
        else if (this.collapse.Name == "expand")
        {
            MovieListView.Width = 1463; 
            MovieListView.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
            sidebar.Width = 0;
            sidebar.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(1463, 0, 0, 0);
            this.collapse.Name = "collapse";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

just use the expander control (set it to what direction you desire eg left up right or down) and dont forget to set the window size to auto.

example:
[WPF Expander Control](http://wpftutorial.net/Expander.html)

Comment: Thanks Sag1v. Will this allow me to have the expanded content appear on the right side of my application if a button is clicked elsewhere?

Comment: Yeah. Just set it to expand to the right (default is down) it comes with a built in button. Glad you got your answer ;)